# Why has_many_and_belongs_to table id is named rowid

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When we use `has_many_and_belongs_to`, another table is also created which contains id of both table. This table automatically generate another column named `row_id` but for other tables this column is named `id`. Why is that?

Comment: Could you post the schema entries (from schema.rb) for the has_many_and_belongs_to table, and the "other table", so we can see clearly what you are comparing?

Comment: And what version of Rails...

Answer (score 1):

When you use `has_many_and_belongs_to`, your join table is literally that -- a join table

---

**[has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)**

The design of this association is that it literally just needs to reference the comparable associations (in your two other models), and therefore doesn't need any primary key:

[image]

It's all about `foreign_keys` and `primary_keys` in [relational databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database). Relational data, by its nature, means that you can access data in other tables which is related. The way Rails (and any other relational system) identifies this data is to use `foreign_keys` (`row_id`)

---

**[has_many :through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)**

If you use `has_many :through`, you need to assign a `primary_key` (`id`), because it has its own model, like so:

[image]

This means that you can reference `has_many :through` records directly, as well as being able to reference relational data. It's all about `primary_keys` and `foreign_keys`